SQL Oracle How to find distinct word but not a word out of context?
I have a table where a column called NOTE has some text. I'm trying to return only the rows that have 'ABC', but not rows that contain 'ABCD', 'ZABC', etc.
I was thinking of something like select * from MY_TABLE where NOTE like '%ABC%' and NOTE not like '%ABCD%'
Do you think this is the most optional solution? Or is there a better way to get rid of the unwanted rows if I just search for ABC? I'm struggling to find a better way to word my question so appreciate any help here.

Also to add, I've only seen instances of ABCD in my table, but if there is a better way to get rid of any other rows (with ZABC for example) that would be great!

I think it would be cleaner to use REGEXP_LIKE()  since it would allow you to scale your matching pattern more elegantly than stringing together a bunch of LIKE and NOT LIKE conditions.  Something like: WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(NOTE, '[^Z]ABC[^D]')

You can use Oracle Text to search using CONTAINS.
If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE my_table ( note ) AS
SELECT 'ABC is what we are looking for' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'We are not looking for ABCD.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'and ZABC does not match either.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'We want ABC and not ABCD or ZABC, but if they are together...' FROM DUAL;

Then you can create the Oracle Text index:
CREATE INDEX my_table__note__textidx ON my_table(note) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;

and use the query:
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  CONTAINS(note, 'ABC') > 0

Which outputs:



NOTE




ABC is what we are looking for


We want ABC and not ABCD or ZABC, but if they are together...




If you do not want to use Oracle Text then you could use regular expressions to match either the start of the string ^ or a non-word character \W before your word and then either a non-word character \W or the end of the string $ after the word:
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(note, '(^|\W)ABC(\W|$)')

Which has the same output for the sample data.
fiddle
